# Setting s3 bucket with replication using Terraform

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to configure s3 bucket with replication using Terraform. I'm getting the following error.

```
Error: insufficient items for attribute "destination"; must have at least 1

      on main.tf line 114, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "ps-db-backups":
     114:   lifecycle_rule {
```

I don't understand this error message. First in the `replication` section I have `destination` defined. Second the error message mentions `lifecycle_rule` which does not have
`destination` attribute. The bucket definition is below.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "ps-db-backups" {
  bucket = "ps-db-backups-b3bd1643-8cbf-4927-a64a-f0cf9b58dfab"
  acl    = "private"
  region = "eu-west-1"

  versioning {
    enabled = true
  }

  lifecycle_rule {
    id      = "transition"
    enabled = true

    transition {
      days          = 30
      storage_class = "STANDARD_IA"
    }

    expiration {
      days = 180
    }
  }

replication_configuration {
    role = "${aws_iam_role.ps-db-backups-replication.arn}"

    rules {
      id     = "ps-db-backups-replication"
      status = "Enabled"

      destination {
        bucket        = "${aws_s3_bucket.ps-db-backups-replica.arn}"
        storage_class = "STANDARD_IA"
      }
    }
  }

server_side_encryption_configuration {
    rule {
      apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
        sse_algorithm     = "AES256"
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: which terraform version are you running with?

Comment: I have upgraded to tha latest 0.12.2 but the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Terraform 0.12.
See this issue https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/9048

Answer (score 0):

Go through the terraform [docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/s3_bucket.html) carefully.

You need to create a separate terraform resource for `destination` like this one:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "destination" {
  bucket = "tf-test-bucket-destination-12345"
  region = "eu-west-1"

  versioning {
    enabled = true
  }
}
```

And then refer it in your `replication_configuration` as

```
destination {
  bucket        = "${aws_s3_bucket.destination.arn}"
  storage_class = "STANDARD"
}
```

I hope this helps. Try and let me know.

Comment: I have that setup obviously. Did not include the whole terraform config file for brewity.

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, if you also need to enable monitoring for S3 replication you won't be able to. Terraform does not have this implemented.

But there's a PR opened for this, please vote with a thumbs UP, https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/pull/11337